# Android - ArrayAdapter, ArrayList and file writer not updating correctly

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-file

Below is code from an activity in an Android App I'm trying to create.  It's a "to do list" that can by dynamically adjusted(add/delete) and saved to a file.  When testing I found the following errors(1) that I can't seem to correct and I have a question(2) :

1. The first few "add" to the list show up as duplicates. Removing adaptor.add vs list.add did not fix it.  If I leave the view and return, the duplication when you "add" stops.  However the file that the list is stored in has duplicates.  I also see errors when I try to "delete" items from the list, but I think the duplication is causing the problem.  How do I stop the duplicate?
2. How can I just completely overwrite the data in the file with the current list in the view?

```
public class ToDo extends ListActivity {

/** Items entered by the user is stored in this ArrayList variable */
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

/** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
ArrayAdapter adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Setting a custom layout for the list activity */
    setContentView(R.layout.content_to_do);

    /** Reference to the add button of the layout main.xml */
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    /** Reference to the delete button of the layout main.xml */
    Button btnDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDel);

    Button btnClr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClr);

    /** Defining the ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "TODOList.ser");
    if(file.exists()) {
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            try {
                // create a file in downloads directory
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                        new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "TODOList.ser")
                );
                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                list = (ArrayList<String>) is.readObject();
                System.out.println(list);

                Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("Data is "+ it.next());
                    adapter.add(it.next());
                }

                is.close();
                Log.v("MyApp","File has been read");
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("MyApp","File wasn't read");
            }
        }
    }
    /** Defining a click event listener for the button "Add" */
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            list.add(edit.getText().toString());
            adapter.add(edit.getText().toString());
            edit.setText("");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
                try {
                    // create a file in downloads directory
                    FileOutputStream fos =
                            new FileOutputStream(
                                    new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "TODOList.ser")
                            );
                    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                    os.writeObject(list);
                    os.close();
                    Log.v("MyApp","File has been written");
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("MyApp","File didn't write");
                }
            }

        }
    };

    /** Defining a click event listener for the button "Delete" */
    OnClickListener listenerDel = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /** Getting the checked items from the listview */
            SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
            int itemCount = getListView().getCount();

            for(int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
                if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
                    adapter.remove(list.get(i));
                    list.remove(i);   //try to adjust array list before write
                }
            }
            checkedItemPositions.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
                try {
                    // create a file in downloads directory
                    FileOutputStream fos =
                            new FileOutputStream(
                                    new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "TODOList.ser")
                            );
                    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                    os.writeObject(list);
                    os.close();
                    Log.v("MyApp","File has been written");
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("MyApp","File didn't write");
                }
            }
        }
    };


    /** Defining a click event listener for the button "Delete" */
    OnClickListener listenerClr = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
                try {
                    File clearit = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "TODOList.ser");
                    clearit.delete();
                    adapter.clear();
                    Log.v("MyApp","File has been deleted");
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("MyApp","File didn't write");
                }
            }
        }
    };


    /** Setting the event listener for the add button */
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

    /** Setting the event listener for the delete button */
    btnDel.setOnClickListener(listenerDel);

    /** Setting the event listener for the clear button */
    btnClr.setOnClickListener(listenerClr);

    /** Setting the adapter to the ListView */
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Comment: As you have added value in list, you don't need to add it in adapter, so remove line "adapter.add(edit.getText().toString());",   just after adding value in list call adapter.notifyDatasethanged so it will resolve your duplication issue

Comment: Yes, I tried that removing list.add and adapter.add each separately, but either got a duplicate of an empty space or the view didn't update correctly.  I'll try again to see if that fixes it.   When the adapter.add is executed should it also update "list" the arraylist variable?